# Python Create Directory Loop with Incremental Format

Tags: python, loops, directory

I would like the script to create a new directory based on the given directories with the same name already in place. Such that if Folder 0 exists, but Folder 1 does not, it creates Folder 1 and stops at one directory creation.

```
import os

i=1
while True:
    path = "Folder_{}/".format(i)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("Folder_{}/".format(i)), exist_ok=False)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("Folder_{}/".format(i)), exist_ok=False)
    i += 1
```

I have tested the above code, and it has quite given me the headache as it creates around 10K directories/second haha. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably not a copy of your real code, as `while:` causes a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, edited 'while True:'. I know I have no break in there but I cannot get it to compile with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
i=1
keepGoing=True
while keepGoing:
  path = "Folder_{}/".format(i)
  if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("Folder_{}/".format(i)), exist_ok=False)
    keepGoing = False
  i += 1
```